# I'm unable to get the output

Tags: java

with a key for every different first character seen, with the value of all the strings starting with that character appended together in the order they appear in the array.

Input:

```
(["salt", "tea", "soda", "toast"])
```

Output:

```
{"s": "saltsoda", "t": "teatoast"}
```

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
String result = "";

for(String s: strings){
  if(map.containsKey(s.substring(0,1))){
    result = result+s;
    map.put(s.substring(0,1),result);
  }else{
    map.put(s.substring(0,1),s);
  }
} 
return map;
```

Comment: "_I'm unable to get the output_" - what output are you getting instead? Your logic seems to be wrong. At most one loop is needed for this task. Also, can you explain why your loops are structured the way they are? What I would do is: 1) Loop once over the input 2) in this loop, check if the `map` already contains the key for the current first character 3) then either append the `String` to the found value for the key or add the new key value pair.

Comment: to append we have store the first appeared string and second loop over entire array for existence.

Comment: Well, actually no. Look at the steps I described in my comment.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments. As you can see, it doesn't look too great. Instead, [edit] your question, to add the code there if it's relevant.

Comment: `result` is never reset inbetween loops. It should be the value currently found in the map or the empty string if not. Currently, you just keep adding to the `result` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the updated code you showed, you are almost there. What you are still missing is, to append the `String`s when a key was already found. In your code the line

```
result = result + s;
```

should actually be:

```
result = map.get(s.substring(0,1)) + s;
```

Also, don't forget to reset the `result` for each loop iteration, as pointed out in the comments.

Here is a working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = { "salt", "tea", "soda", "toast" };
    Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : input) {
        String first = s.substring(0, 1);
        if (output.containsKey(first)) {
            output.put(first, output.get(first) + s);
        } else {
            output.put(first, s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output:

```
{s=saltsoda, t=teatoast}
```

Or better, with `Character` as the key instead of `String`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = { "salt", "tea", "soda", "toast" };
    Map<Character, String> output = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : input) {
        char c = s.charAt(0);
        if (output.containsKey(c)) {
            output.put(c, output.get(c) + s);
        } else {
            output.put(c, s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output:

```
{s=saltsoda, t=teatoast}
```

Or you could also use Java8 Streams to do the job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = { "salt", "tea", "soda", "toast" };
    Map<Character, String> output = 
            Stream.of(input) // create stream of the strings
                .collect(Collectors.toMap( // collect
                    k -> k.charAt(0),      // key should be first char
                    v -> v,                // value should be the string
                    (s1, s2) -> {          // mergeFunction, in case the key exists
                         return s1 + s2;   // then append the strings
                    }
            ));
    System.out.println(output);
}
```